# Angular2 - multiple router-outlets/components on routes

Tags: angular, router, outlet

Is there any possibility to specify a router-outlet? Maybe with an ID or something?

This is what i need to do:

```
@routes:{path:'/data', component:datacomponent},
        {path:'/charts, component:chartcomponent},
        {path: '/overview', component:???chartcomponent,datacomponent???}
```

I either need to be  able to insert multiple components into one route, or to specify the router-outlet(if it is possible to use the same path twice or more often).

As you can see, this is Angular2. 
There is actually no way that I'm using the router-deprecated, because I need to have the providers and directives from the new router to keep my app running.

Comment: I think there is but I don't remember. It didn't work properly anyway as far as I know. I guess it's better to wait for the new new router.

Comment: Isn't that what aux routes are for?

Comment: I'm actually really new to programming itself and thus to Angular2, too. Would you mind explaning how they work? Or do you have a working example? Would be awesome!

Comment: [Here](http://ngcourse.rangle.io/handout/routing/using_auxiliary_routes.html) is an example. It uses the old (deprecated) beta router though.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with the new @Routes.. aux is not assignable to RouteMetaData. :/ Anyway, thanks to you.